# Are thread pools safe and is use of them recommended?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

I was researching the answer to this question and ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12752215/3099965) post.  Is ThreadPool safe?  How does ThreadPool compare with the OmniThreadLibrary?  What are the pluses and minuses of using each?

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
procedure DoWork(nameList: TList<Integer>)
var
  i: Integer;
  oneThread: PerNameThread;
begin
  for (i := 0; to nameList.Count-1) do
  begin
    oneThread := PerNameThread.Create(Self);
    oneThread.nameID = nameList[i];
    oneThread.Start();
  end
end;
```

I am creating a thread for each nameList item, and this could be up to 500 names.  All these threads are too much, and slowing down the process, to the point where this process would be faster with just one thread.

Comment: That's not a thread pool. Threads in a thread pool can perform multiple tasks. You create one thread per task. You have over subscription. Use a real thread pool. They are good.

Comment: @David, my interpretation of the question is that Kevin *knows* that's not a thread pool. He has recognized some shortcomings with the existing code and is asking whether a thread pool would improve it, and if so, how OmniThreadLibrary compares to the ThreadPool unit given by Martin James in the linked answer.

Comment: Isn't there too much scope for opinion in the question?

Comment: @Graymatter. Why? Is there someone who has an itchy mouse finger looking for a post to close or put on hold?

Comment: On top of it, try to do this with 5000 names and an operation that takes some time. You will run into big trouble doing it this way. And it will not be the slowdown that is your problem.

Comment: @Blurry Multiple close reasons apply here. This question is enormously vague. Are they safe? Safe from what? What are the pros and cons? Well, what is the use case? Are we expected to write a book?

Comment: "Are we expected to write a book?" Definitely not. It just seems that moderators on SO forget that they too were newbies once. We need to coach people to properly fit into the culture here. The strength of a community does not only rely on the experience of existing members but also on the amount of new inexperienced members. I just think that we can be a bit more forgiving and maybe try to point the new ones into the right direction.

Comment: @Blurry That's one of the points of closing. Teach people how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand what a thread pool is.

A thread pool is a concept where you have a list of multiple threads that are suspended when they are not performing any tasks.

These threads are defined a bit differently than you are probably used to. Instead of them having all the necessary code inside their `Execute()` method,  their `Execute()` method only contains a few lines of code to execute external code (giving the threads the ability to perform practically any processing that you require), take care of synchronizing the result back to the caller/UI, and returning the thread to the pool and putting it into a suspended state.  When a new task is needed at a later time, a thread is given the task and resumed.
So by providing each thread with a method pointer for a task, you actually define what kind of job each thread will be processing each time it is run.

The main advantage of using a thread pool is that doing so avoids the overhead of creating and destroying a thread for each specific task.

As for OmniThreadLibrary, it is a full blown task management library. It uses its own thread pool and a pretty advanced task managing system that allows you to easily define which tasks can be executed in parallel, which tasks need to be executed in sequence, and which tasks have higher priority than others.

The only drawback of OmniThreadLibrary is that it is still limited to Windows only, so if you are thinking of providing multiplatform support for your application then you will have to find another solution.